# test multiple spring boot applications with one embedded Jetty server

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, embedded-jetty

We are developing a product that consists of several modules , most of the modules are independent but they represent a rest API developed using Spring MVC framework,
Now, we are thinking of putting a full automated integrated test plan, I started using the Spring Boot application with embedded Jetty server and H2 DB for one of the applications and it worked great 
But how can I achieve this for the rest of modules, I mean use a single embedded Jetty server to test all Spring boot applications at once, is this possible?

Comment: Because once you add the dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web` in your pom file, your application will be standalone web application automatically. Therefore, I don't think it is a good method to share the same web container for multiple applications under Spring framework.

Comment: Will, i used a spring boot application to make the testing process easier but at the end all modules will be deployed on a separate server, do you have any suggestions

Comment: If you want to perform integration test with these applications, either to start up each of them or you can test your services with mocking.

Comment: you mean start each one of them on a different port? would you please explain more about the later option " with mocking"

Comment: Mock (Mock object) is a technique used during unit testing. Which can simulate the scenario of the communication between services. You can search the keyword on web, there are rich explanation and examples. Good luck!

Comment: Ok sure I will google this, but I was thinking of 
creating a single spring boot application to test all modules, I mean include all modules as dependencies in this project, and then run the application and test all modules, I need to see how to deploy multiple contexts, but what do you think about the approach